# How to route WWW URL to non-WWW URL for ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, iis

We have an ASP.NET MVC4 website "mysite.com" on IIS 7.5 with pages that make AJAX calls back to the same server using jQuery AJAX.

If the user logs into the site as http://testsite.com the AJAX call to testsite.com/cases?id=4 works properly. However, if the user logs into http:www.testsite.com and the same AJAX call is made it fails because it is considered cross-domain (www.testsite.com vs testsite.com).

Where would we address the issue of accepting AJAX calls to "www.testsite.com" as if they were to "testsite.com" so the call is not considered cross-domain? Is this something that can be addressed at the IIS level or in the MVC site itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use relative URLs in your Ajax it will match the current domain/subdomain that the user is on. This way they'll get WWW or NON-WWW depending on how they login.

```
//...
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Controller/Page",
//...
```

Instead of

```
//...
    type: "POST",
    url: "//testsite.com/Controller/Page",
//...
```